# H2 Database Exception: Table "CONSTANTS" not found

Tags: java, spring, h2, spring-boot-starter, spring-boot-starter-parent

I upgraded **spring-boot-starter-parent** to ***2.7.5*** (*from 2.6.8*), and now I got the following exception in unit tests which I don't have such table (*CONSTANTS*)

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CONSTANTS" not found
```

The full stacktrace is below:

```
org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CONSTANTS" not found; SQL statement:
select CONSTANT_CATALOG, CONSTANT_SCHEMA, CONSTANT_NAME, VALUE_DEFINITION, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH, CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG, CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA, CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLLATION_CATALOG, COLLATION_SCHEMA, COLLATION_NAME, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, NUMERIC_SCALE, DATETIME_PRECISION, INTERVAL_TYPE, INTERVAL_PRECISION, MAXIMUM_CARDINALITY, DTD_IDENTIFIER, DECLARED_DATA_TYPE, DECLARED_NUMERIC_PRECISION, DECLARED_NUMERIC_SCALE, GEOMETRY_TYPE, GEOMETRY_SRID, REMARKS from CONSTANTS [42102-214]

at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTable(DatabaseDataSet.java:342)
at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseTableIterator.getTable(DatabaseTableIterator.java:89)
at org.dbunit.dataset.stream.DataSetProducerAdapter.produce(DataSetProducerAdapter.java:83)
at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlWriter.write(FlatXmlWriter.java:124)
at org.dbunit.dataset.xml.FlatXmlDataSet.write(FlatXmlDataSet.java:378)
at my.own.package.util.Test.extractDataSet(AbstractJobIntegrationTest.java:221)
at my.own.package.configuration.util.AbstractJobIntegrationTest.getActualMidasConfigurationDataSet(AbstractJobIntegrationTest.java:206)
at my.own.package.configuration.util.Test.assertDatabase(AbstractJobIntegrationTest.java:197)
at my.own.package.configuration.IntegrationTest.testSuccess(CallCreditIntegrationTest.java:76)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CONSTANTS" not found; SQL statement:
*emphasized text*select CONSTANT_CATALOG, CONSTANT_SCHEMA, CONSTANT_NAME, VALUE_DEFINITION, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH, CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG, CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA, CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLLATION_CATALOG, COLLATION_SCHEMA, COLLATION_NAME, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, NUMERIC_SCALE, DATETIME_PRECISION, INTERVAL_TYPE, INTERVAL_PRECISION, MAXIMUM_CARDINALITY, DTD_IDENTIFIER, DECLARED_DATA_TYPE, DECLARED_NUMERIC_PRECISION, DECLARED_NUMERIC_SCALE, GEOMETRY_TYPE, GEOMETRY_SRID, REMARKS from CONSTANTS [42102-214]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8398)
at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8369)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8358)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTablePrimary(Parser.java:1863)
at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableReference(Parser.java:2334)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2772)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2878)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2762)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2633)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2612)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2605)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2598)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2567)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:724)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689)
at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569)
at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:92)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeQuery(ProxyStatement.java:110)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyStatement.java)
at org.dbunit.database.AbstractResultSetTable.<init>(AbstractResultSetTable.java:110)
at org.dbunit.database.ForwardOnlyResultSetTable.<init>(ForwardOnlyResultSetTable.java:59)
at org.dbunit.database.CachedResultSetTableFactory.createTable(CachedResultSetTableFactory.java:60)
at org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet.getTable(DatabaseDataSet.java:338)
... 77 more
```

The application.yml:

```
app:
 datasource:
  mydb-configuration:
   jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;NON_KEYWORDS=VALUE
   username: sa
   password:
   driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

pom.xml:

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
...
```

What can be done to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you expect to have created the database schema for you? I can't see anything in what you've shared thus far that would do it.

Comment: `CONSTANTS` is actually a built-in virtual system table in H2, but it should be qualified with a schema name (`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTANTS`) in queries.

Comment: Thanks, @EvgenijRyazanov. So this will be due to the breaking changes in H2 2.x. kamal, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#h2-21 for further details.

Comment: All versions of H2 have that table, and for all of them it needs to be qualified with a schema. So one of libraries in your application has some strange bug here. You can try to add `;SCHEMA_SEARCH_PATH=INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to JDBC URL as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have?

```
spring:
  test:
    database:
      replace: none
```

Comment: I don't have such thing in application.yml, what is this for?
Nevertheless it is not the solution, just tried it